# How to compare a string within a another string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

How to compare a string within a another string?

Example:

```
NSString *temp = @"english, french, japanese, chinese";
NSString *jap = @"japanese";
```

How do i compare the string "japanese" in temp with the string "japanese" in jap.

Is there any function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?

Answer (score 0):

You wan't to check if the string `temp` contains the string `jap`? You can use the NSString method `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`. It returns you the range if it has found the aString in the receiver or a `{NSNotFound, 0}` if nothing was found.

Answer (score 0):

if([teststring isEqualToString:teststring2]==TRUE)

dosomethink();

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *temp = @"english, french, japanese, chinese";
NSString *jap = @"japanese";
NSRange foundObj=[temp rangeOfString:jap options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(foundObj.length>0) { 
    NSLog(@"Yes ! Jap found"); 
} else {
    NSLog(@"Oops ! no jap"); 
}
```